# What are the system requirements for comfortable running IBM Cloud Private Community Edition(ICP CE)?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I'm trying to run IBM Cloud Private.
I saw [Hardware requirements and recommendations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_3.1.0/supported_system_config/hardware_reqs.html), but I'm not sure that the spec is enough for me.
I'd liked to run several cloud foundry applications, MessageSight, Spinnaker, and so on.

How do you think this spec?
CPU: 3GHz 10core 
Mem: 64GB
HDD: 2TB (SSD)

Answer (score 0):

I did a Terraform script for this together with CentOS 7.6
And the minimum I use is following config, and count with 250GB as minimum disk size.
This is applying for ICP CE 3.1.1

```
##### ICP Cluster Components #####
master = {
    nodes = "3"
    vcpu = "8"
    memory = "16384"
    docker_disk_size = "250"
    thin_provisioned = "true"
    thin_provisioned_etcd = "false"
}
proxy = {
    nodes = "3"
    vcpu = "4"
    memory = "8192"
    thin_provisioned = "true"
}
worker = {
    nodes = "3"
    vcpu = "8"
    memory = "8192"
    thin_provisioned = "true"
}
management = {
    nodes = "3"
    vcpu = "4"
    memory = "16384"
    thin_provisioned = "true"
}
va = {
    nodes = "2"
    vcpu = "4"
    memory = "8192"
    thin_provisioned = "true"
}
```